# react-testing-library - appending characters to an input or text area

Tags: react-testing-library

I have a use case where I need to type a few characters into a text area, test something, and then append more characters into that text area. How do I do this? If I call `fireEvent.change()` twice in succession, the second call overwrites the content, instead of appending to it.

```
fireEvent.change(getByTestId('text-txt-area'), {
    target: { value: '123' }
});

// Overwrites '123' instead of appending '456'
fireEvent.change(getByTestId('text-txt-area'), {
    target: { value: '456' }
});
```

Comment: That's what `change` is *supposed* to do, change the old value to the new value. Have you tried https://testing-library.com/docs/ecosystem-user-event?

Comment: Thanks so much, @jonrsharpe. `userEvent.type()` works like a charm! Can you please formally answer the question so that I can mark it as correct!

Comment: Maybe you should to fire `blur` event before second typing?

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to append text, you should use [userEvent.type](https://testing-library.com/docs/user-event/utility#type)

> You can use type() if you just want to conveniently insert some text into an input field or textarea.

Be careful, as its implementation has changed from version to version.  Starting with v14, everything returns a promise, but in earlier releases its return type was conditional based on whether a `delay` was provided.